# How to view .mdb dataset on kaggle?

Tags: kaggle

I load this [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/kerneler/starter-clova-deep-text-lmdb-dataset-b9edca2b-d/data) in this way:

```
Add data > Search for the dataset name (clova deep text ...) > Add
```

After the dataset is loaded and is visible in the sidebar, I found a `data.mdb` and `lock.mdb` inside every subfolder. I need to examine the contents, view images, view labels ... What should I do to open / view contents in / modify this weird format?

[image: sidebar]

Based on [Luke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14472571/luke)'s suggestion I tried `apt install mbtools`, the installation starts and I'm prompted to enter `y/n` and unable to because the cell doesn't let you. If I try passing `-y` I get a `unrecognized argument` thing. Then I tried the following which complains about the missing package.

```
pip install mbtools meza
from meza import io    
records = io.read('/kaggle/input/clova-deeptext/clova_deeptext/data_lmdb_release/training/ST/data.mdb')
print(next(records))
```

result:

```
Collecting mbtools
  Downloading mbtools-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (3.7 kB)
Collecting meza
  Downloading meza-0.42.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (55 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 55 kB 165 kB/s eta 0:00:01
Collecting ijson<3.0.0,>=2.3
  Downloading ijson-2.6.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (65 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 65 kB 352 kB/s eta 0:00:01
Collecting python-slugify<2.0.0,>=1.2.5
  Downloading python-slugify-1.2.6.tar.gz (6.8 kB)
Collecting dbfread==2.0.4
  Downloading dbfread-2.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4<5.0.0,>=4.6.0 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from meza) (4.10.0)
Collecting pygogo<0.15.0,>=0.13.2
  Downloading pygogo-0.13.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.18.4 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from meza) (2.25.1)
Collecting xlrd<2.0.0,>=1.1.0
  Downloading xlrd-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (103 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 103 kB 1.0 MB/s eta 0:00:01
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML<6.0.0,>=4.2b1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from meza) (5.4.1)
Collecting chardet<4.0.0,>=3.0.4
  Downloading chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 133 kB 987 kB/s eta 0:00:01
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.7.2 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from meza) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>1.2 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from beautifulsoup4<5.0.0,>=4.6.0->meza) (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.7.2->meza) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Unidecode>=0.04.16 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from python-slugify<2.0.0,>=1.2.5->meza) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.18.4->meza) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.18.4->meza) (2021.5.30)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests<3.0.0,>=2.18.4->meza) (1.26.6)
Building wheels for collected packages: python-slugify
  Building wheel for python-slugify (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for python-slugify: filename=python_slugify-1.2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=4609 sha256=8c4763108a666b347806541ae6fa0fb59656f9ea38406507f7c83fd06d7621e9
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/c5/02/83/9904a9436aa0205c8daa9127109e9ed50d3eab25a5ea2fcb9f
Successfully built python-slugify
Installing collected packages: chardet, xlrd, python-slugify, pygogo, ijson, dbfread, meza, mbtools
  Attempting uninstall: chardet
    Found existing installation: chardet 4.0.0
    Uninstalling chardet-4.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled chardet-4.0.0
  Attempting uninstall: python-slugify
    Found existing installation: python-slugify 5.0.2
    Uninstalling python-slugify-5.0.2:
      Successfully uninstalled python-slugify-5.0.2
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
caip-notebooks-serverextension 1.0.0 requires google-cloud-bigquery-storage, which is not installed.
jupyterlab-git 0.11.0 requires nbdime<2.0.0,>=1.1.0, but you have nbdime 3.1.0 which is incompatible.
gcsfs 2021.7.0 requires fsspec==2021.07.0, but you have fsspec 2021.8.1 which is incompatible.
earthengine-api 0.1.283 requires google-api-python-client<2,>=1.12.1, but you have google-api-python-client 1.8.0 which is incompatible.
aiobotocore 1.4.1 requires botocore<1.20.107,>=1.20.106, but you have botocore 1.21.44 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed chardet-3.0.4 dbfread-2.0.4 ijson-2.6.1 mbtools-0.1.1 meza-0.42.5 pygogo-0.13.2 python-slugify-1.2.6 xlrd-1.2.0
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
You must install [mdbtools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mdbtools/) in order to use this function
```

Comment: Are you using Python?

Comment: Yeah, this is the notebook's sidebar view

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following snippet:

```py
!sudo apt install mdbtools #  Library that allows access to MDB files programatically
!pip install meza # A Python toolkit for processing tabular data

from meza import io

records = io.read('database.mdb') # Use only file path, not file objects
print(next(records))
```

Comment: Upvote and Accept this answer if it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution (Helps the SO Community)

Comment: Sure, I will. I'm checking now but there is some unknown problem which makes `apt` unable to connect to ubuntu server, so I'll do what needs to be done and try again

Comment: The stupid cell shows `Do you want to continue? [Y/n] ` without allowing you to click anywhere to respond. I tried `apt install mdbtools -y` and the problems persists

Comment: Post the issue in your question

Comment: Use `!pip install mdbtools`

Comment: I did install the pip package and I was notified `you must install mbtools to use this package`

Comment: I pip installed the package myself on kaggle and it worked

Comment: I added the log I get when I run `pip install mbtools meza` and currently trying it on the dataset.